# Linux (Bash) - Create a PDF with a form with editable fields from the Acrobat Reader

Tags: linux, forms, bash, pdf, fdf

Is it possible to create from Linux, from the command line (bash), a PDF that contains a form with fields that can then be edited with Acrobat Reader?

Answer (score 3):

The first approach could be creating a LaTeX file with your form and generating the PDF file using a bash command.

For instance, the [Creating Fillable PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs) post explains how to write a LaTeX file to produce a PDF form.

Once you have written all the LaTeX files, you could simply run:

```
$ pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode ${latexFile}
```

Where the `-interaction=nonstopmode` flag disables the user interaction and the `${latexFile}` points to your latex source file

Comment: I wan't aware of the -interaction option.  That's good to know.  That said, LaTeX may require multiple passes depending upon the content.  I also doubt that you would be able to create the forms or the ActionScript to drive them inside of LaTeX.

Comment: @Sebosin Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible.

You can pick a programming language with good pdf library supported, E.g java and itext, design your pdf layout, decide which fields should be editable. Then generate the pdf.

In shell you just call the program you've developed.

If you ask for pure bash itself, No, it cannot do it for you.